"Did the maser blind you?" Young adult dystopian story - older girl and younger boy fighting the regime
What I remember is:

A near-future dystopian city. Standard YA science fiction dystopia. Riot police, young people fighting back, etc.
A young-ish boy (pre-teen, teenager?) is caught in the middle of a fight with the police/government forces. He manages to retreat, but some kind of weapon has hit him and his eyes are watering. A slightly older girl, almost like a big sister, sits next to him, tends to his wounds, and asks something like: "What's the matter? Did the maser blind you?" or "Aw, did the maser blind you?"
Presumably this means the government forces/riot police carry and use maser weapons in the story as some kind of crowd-control weapon.

Context: I would imagine the year I read this is around 1997-2001 in the UK. I would have been reading a YA SF novel. Maybe a "Choose Your Own Adventure" book, probably published in the 80s or 90s. However, that isn't exactly what I'm trying to remember - I don't think this was a "Choose Your Own Adventure" book but might have come from the same publisher or a similar author etc.
At the end of some books there would be a "sneak peek" or "preview" chapter of another book in the series or a book from the same publisher. It's this story I'm trying to identify. (Of course, it is possible the full story was never published and it only exists as a preview!)
I remember that "Did the maser blind you?" sentence so vividly, because it was the first time I'd seen the word "maser". But all kinds of searches for SF stories involving masers don't come up with anything like what I remember. I'd love to know if anyone has any ideas.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you remember any details of the cover art of the book you read this in?

@DavidW Nothing at all, I'm afraid.

One of the problems here is that masers don't blind people, except by cooking their heads, which wouldn't normally be considered "blinding" someone.

I can remember some science fiction from probably the early 60s where the term "optical maser" was used, instead of "laser". Probably not relevant to the question.

@DavidW, masers might not, but mace might
